# How do I print the local task bar in different places depending on the base route?

Tags: 8, theming

I want to print the local task bar used when users register/login/reset password at another part of the page, than the other local task bars.

The base route for these menu links is *user.page*.

https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8d0135d52be12024d70036420f271677ab6aa7d9/core/modules/user/user.links.task.yml#L11-L26

Can I use twig to achieve this? Or do I need to use some preprocessing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local tasks is just a block, meaning you can use all the tools that blocks give you. Create two blocks, put them in both locations where you want to see it. On one block, configure path visibility to only show on user/*, on the other one, configure it to show everywhere except on user/*.